# Reading data from MongoDB that contains array using Talend

Tags: arrays, mongodb, talend

I have a collection in my MongoDB that contains one field that is an array.

[image]

Refer to the data above, the field 'Courses' is an array.

The JSON format of the data is like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb59b98a970a20865142e8"
    },
    "Name": "Sadia",
    "Age": 24,
    "Institute": "IBA",
    "Courses": [{
        "Name": "ITP",
        "Grade": "A-"
    }, {
        "Name": "OOP",
        "Grade": "A-"
    }]
}
```

I am aware that there is a way in case its an object, but could not find a way on how to read this data using Talend since it contains an array.